# Make animation on counter repeat it self after scroll of and scroll back

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help with counter of social media followers on my page. I have got working animation counterUP.js that does what it says, when the page is opened for ther first time, the number will counter up and thats fine but I have to figure out how can I do this: If anyone scroll to the counter, the number will counter up, if the person scroll off of these number and scroll back to them, they will counterUP again. Now what it does, they counterUP one time and thats it.

thank you for answers. 
Code here:

//This is the item in html

```
<div class="single-item-counter">   
<a class="item twitter">
<span class="counter">66,093</span>
</a>
<p>twitter<i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true">
</i>
</p>
</div>
```

//This is counterup javascript

```
(function(e){"use strict";e.fn.counterUp=function(t){var 
n=e.extend({time:400,delay:10},t);return this.each(function(){var 
t=e(this),r=n,i=function(){var e=[],n=r.time/r.delay,i=t.text(),s=/[0-9]+, 
[0-9]+/.test(i);i=i.replace(/,/g,"");var o=/^[0-9]+$/.test(i),u=/^[0-9]+\. 
[0-9]+$/.test(i),a=u?(i.split(".")[1]||[]).length:0;for(var f=n;f>=1;f--) 
{var l=parseInt(i/n*f);u&& 
(l=parseFloat(i/n*f).toFixed(a));if(s)while(/(\d+) 
(\d{3})/.test(l.toString()))l=l.toString().replace(/(\d+) 
(\d{3})/,"$1,$2");e.unshift(l)}t.data("counterup-nums",e);t.text("0");var 
c=function(){t.text(t.data("counterup- 
nums").shift());if(t.data("counterup- 
nums").length)setTimeout(t.data("counterup-func"),r.delay);else{delete 
t.data("counterup-nums");t.data("counterup-nums",null);t.data("counterup- 
func",null)}};t.data("counterup-func",c);setTimeout(t.data("counterup- 
func"),r.delay)};t.waypoint(i,{offset:"100%",triggerOnce:!0})})}})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Count up again what? If the count is 10.... starts at 0, user scrolls, it animates to 10 and now the display is 10... you want the display to count down as user scrolls away and they starts counting up as user scrolls near? Doesn't sound like a counter, sounds more like a distance calculator from user's mouse and the number. Getting hot hot hot... cold cold cold, hot hot hot.

Comment: yes, count up again. I though that its gonna be thing of scrollup script just because it starts when user scroll to it, not when the page is opened.